# Extract PEM Public Key from X.509 Certificate

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa, pem, der

I've created what I believe is a certificate containing a Public Key DER file, but I need the Public Key in PEM format now for a different platform. The aim is to use the same public key.

I created it using [RSA Encryption in iOS and Decrypt It Using PHP](http://jslim.net/blog/2013/01/05/rsa-encryption-in-ios-and-decrypt-it-using-php/):

```
openssl req -x509 -out public_key.der -outform der -new -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout private_key.pem -days 3650
```

I have an existing public key in use (public_key.der) and can't change it. However I now need a PEM version of the public key

```
public_key.pem
```

How can I convert from DER to PEM in this way?

Note: If I had created my keypair using the following method, things would be easy. I could extract a public key PEM file:

```
openssl genrsa -out rsa.pem 1024 
openssl rsa -in rsa.pem -pubout
```

Public PEM files generated this way work. **Is it possible** that what I've created eariler on (with the `-x590` command) are entirely different creatures to the output of the `rsa` commands?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming you've created certificate in DER format with the command

```
openssl req -x509 -out certificate.der -outform der -new -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout private_key.pem -days 3650
```

Then extracting public key in PEM format can be done with a command

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.der -pubkey -noout > public_key.pem
```

`-inform` defines certificate format (default is PEM) and `-noout` suppresses output except of requested `-pubkey`.

The same operation with certificate in PEM format:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -pubkey -noout > public_key.pem
```